# SEC_TO_TIME SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

This function converts second to time in SQL Server:

```
Create function [dbo].[SEC_TO_TIME](@seconds1 INT)
returns VARCHAR(8)
As
Begin 
    DECLARE @time1 VARCHAR(8);
    SET @time1  SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), DATEADD(second, @seconds1, 0), 108);
    return @time1;
end 
GO
```

But I get an error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure SEC_TO_TIME, Line 7
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.

I tried executing this query which works fine.

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), DATEADD(second, 180, 0), 108);
```

Can you please help me to fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Create function [dbo].[SEC_TO_TIME](@seconds1 INT)
returns VARCHAR(8)
As
Begin 
    DECLARE @time1 VARCHAR(8)
    SET @time1=CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), DATEADD(second, @seconds1, 0), 108)
    return @time1
end 
GO
```

[check this link](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1267163-338-1.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

It is bad idea to return `datetime` as `varchar`.

```
Create function [dbo].[SEC_TO_TIME](@seconds1 INT)
returns datetime
As
Begin 
    RETURN DATEADD(second, @seconds1, 0)
end
```